# only allow ip from australia

Tags: ip, ip-address

i want to only allow website visitors from australia.
has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for GeoIP data to base your restrictions on. There are [lots](http://www.geoiptool.com/) of [resources](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) for this kind of thing around.

However, this is not foolproof and can be circumvented, for example by people using a proxy in Australia.

Answer (score 5):

Try a service such as http://www.maxmind.com/ or http://hostip.info/

They can tell you where a user is located.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest I have tried this, and it has never been a good idea. Even with a paid maxmind database I have had verified locals not being able to access the site. Several reasons come to mind, they maybe using a secure proxy to filter content or whatever. 
If you are doing this for a limited set of visitors (like employees of a company) or to reduce possibility of attacks from outside source then yes its a workable solution.
In all cases, for production WWW I have had to eventually remove the country specific filters.